# How to send friend requests on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

How can I allow my app users to send friend requests to a specific Facebook user, me for instance, directly from my app? I have the Facebook SDK in my app. I tried searching for solution online but couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by the SDK directly, as recorded [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/friendrequests). The friends dialog is no longer supported either. To my knowledge, this is no longer possible, which may make some sense since Facebook does not want friend requests to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding friends is not possible through the API

You can call http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=[USER UID]

Where [USER UID] is a valid facebook user id.

Source : Pixel | StackOverflow